# Compiz CPU Usage is very High

Tags: compiz

I know I am far from the first one to ask this question, but I have a new ***12.10 64-bit*** install, and the CPU usage for compiz is terrible.  I am guessing my quad core would explain the 300% usage on top.

I have tried installing ***CCSM*** and setting ***Sync to VBlank*** off, and the strace described in another link (it locked up my machine)

I have an ***AMD HD7770*** card (Cape Verde).

Is there any late breaking news on how to address this problem, that I may have missed?
Thanks

This is the result of lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde [Radeon HD 7700 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 2304
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at f7d40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: Did you install the Proprietary drivers?

Comment: I believe they were installed automatically.  Is there a way to check?

Comment: Isnt there breakage on the AMD drivers on 12.10?

Comment: @EdgeCase you're using the open source drivers. Open system settings, go to software sources, and check for proprietary drivers under the additional drivers tab. They are **not** installed automatically.

Comment: @BrunoPereira only for older cards.

Comment: I just downloaded the AMD Drivers from http://support.amd.com/de/kbarticles/Pages/hd7700linuxsupport.aspx and installed them.  I totally broke my system.  I had to reinstall.  I saw some messages from unity saying that some operations are not supported.  I think I like the open-source drivers better :)